# Finding Median in sql server upto every date in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, median

I use below query to find the median for every sector

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sector,
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN
GROUP (ORDER BY Value) OVER (PARTITION BY sector) AS Median
FROM TABLE
```

The table is in below format

```
    Sector  Date    Value
    A   2014-08-01  1
    B   2014-08-01  5
    C   2014-08-01  7
    A   2014-08-02  6
    B   2014-08-02  5
    C   2014-08-02  4
    A   2014-08-03  3
    B   2014-08-03  9
    C   2014-08-03  6
    A   2014-08-04  5
    B   2014-08-04  8
    C   2014-08-04  9
    A   2014-08-05  5
    B   2014-08-05  7
    C   2014-08-05  2
```

So I get the expected result as below

```
    Sector  Median
    A   5
    B   7
    C   6
```

Now I need to change the process such that the Medians are calculated while only considering the records upto the given date. So the new result would be

```
    Sector  Date    Value
    A   2014-08-01  1
    B   2014-08-01  5
    C   2014-08-01  7 (Only 1 record each was considered for A, B and C) 

    A   2014-08-02  3.5
    B   2014-08-02  5
    C   2014-08-02  5.5 (2 records each was considered for A, B and C)

    A   2014-08-03  3
    B   2014-08-03  5
    C   2014-08-03  6 (3 records each was considered for A, B and C)

    A   2014-08-04  4
    B   2014-08-04  6.5
    C   2014-08-04  6.5 (4 records each was considered for A, B and C)

    A   2014-08-05  5
    B   2014-08-05  7
    C   2014-08-05  6 (All 5 records each was considered for A, B and C)
```

So this will be sort of a cumulative median. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this. My table has about 2.3M records with about 1100 records each for about 1100 dates.

Please let me know if you need any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes it harder, because the following does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sector, Date,
       PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Value) OVER (PARTITION BY sector ORDER BY DATE) AS Median
FROM TABLE;
```

Alas.  You can use `cross apply` for this purpose:

```
select t.sector, t.date, t.value, m.median
from table t cross apply
     (select top 1 PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY sector ORDER BY t2.DATE) AS Median
      from table t2
      where t2.sector = t.sector and t2.date <= t.date
     ) m;
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you. This seems to be working well in my test dataset. Now I am running it against the huge table. Lets hope all goes fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to create a triangular `JOIN` to get all the past value for every day and use that as the data

```
;With T AS (
  SELECT t2.Sector, t2.[Date], t1.[Value]
  FROM   Table1 t1
         LEFT  JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.Sector = t2.Sector and t1.[Date] <= t2.[Date]
)
SELECT DISTINCT Sector
     , [Date]
     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Value]) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY sector, [Date]) AS Median 
FROM   T
ORDER BY [Date], Sector;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be0d9/18)</kbd>

In the query I've changed `PERCENTILE_DISC` with `PERCENTILE_CONT` to get the right median in case of even number of values, for example the second day.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you for your answer. I have changed my PERCENTILE_DISC to PERCENTILE_CONT